# Linux Mint XFCE - No wireless networks found

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, xfce, thinkpad

I've been troubleshooting this issue for two days now, trying various fixes I've found online to no avail. I'm using a Thinkpad X1 Carbon (6th gen) and dualbooting Win10 and Mint (18.3). Wifi works as intended on Win10 but neither NetworkManager nor WICD can recognize any wifi networks in Mint.

Here is output for lspci -v | grep -A 10 -i "Network Controller":

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at ee200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

I downloaded the iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz file from Intel's website: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

I followed the instructions on this post: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=247531 and ran

```
sudo cp iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode /lib/firmware/
```

Followed by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

which gave me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
```

I downloaded the .deb file from here https://pkgs.org/download/linux-headers-4.15.0-20, ran dpkg -i and got the following output:

```
(Reading database ... 317506 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic_4.15.0-20.21~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic (4.15.0-20.21~16.04.1) over (4.15.0-20.21~16.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic (4.15.0-20.21~16.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.60/build/make.log for more information.
```

Not sure where to go from here.

For transparency I posted this on the Mint forums as well with no responses.

Comment: I suspect the firmware version you are trying to use it not supported. I would check if there is an official Debian/Mint version.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I could not find any official versions. Is there anything else I can do or should I just change to a distro that will support my card?

Comment: I'm running Linux Mint KDE 18.3 and had a similar problem when I upgraded my kernel to 4.15.0-20. I had been running 4.15.0-15 w/o a problem and I switched back to that kernel (at least for now)

Answer (score 1):

When I originally posted this I was running on the 4.15.0-20 kernel. From GRUB I launched Mint from the 4.10.0-38 kernel. The 4.10 version recognizes wireless networks and works perfectly.

I'm still unsure exactly why 4.15.0-20 wouldn't recognize the networks, I assume it has to do with iwlwifi-8265-22 not being compatible with that specific kernel.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change made in 4.15 kernel packages, try

`sudo apt-get install linux-base linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic`

Reboot